# how to change magento design by using a module

Tags: magento, module

I am new in magento.I want to change the design of product list and product view page, but i don't know how it possible.I don't want to change the theme core files.Is there any way to change the design through a module.Any one please help me

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. You are using Gomage Advanced Navigation, right? What do you want to change at this module?